# android camera jpeg file size much larger than iphone?

Tags: android, iphone, image, jpeg, android-camera

My application takes pictures of documents.  I specify a picture size of 1600x1200 on the camera, request a JPEG image, and set quality of 30.

The iPhone developer working on the iPhone version of the application does the same thing (1600 x 1200, quality = 30).

Image sizes:

On an iPhone 4S:  ~100k
Samsung Galaxy Nexus:  ~240k
Samsung Galaxy S3: ~600k

I verified that all the images are in JPEG format and all are 1600 x 1200.  When I visually inspect the image quality they look roughly the same.

Why the difference in file sizes?  What surprised me the most is the difference between the Nexus and S3, since they're running the *exact* same Android code.

Comment: Addendum:  I changed the JPEG quality from 30 to 10 on the Galaxy Nexus.  Picture size went from 240k to 200k.  Image quality was noticeably degraded.  How is the iPhone able to produce a ~100k JPEG with the same dimensions but noticeably *better* image quality?

Comment: "since they're running the exact same Android code." They don't. Manufacturers adjust the code to their devices especially when the code is about hardware that is pretty unique to the device. Both devices have most likely different camera modules. On a sidenote: did you photograph about the same thing? Jpg gets larger when there is more detail in the picture

Comment: I meant my app code is the same.  Yes, photographing the same thing.  (The front of a check, with the check filling the viewable area.)

I wouldn't think the camera module would matter since, at the end of the day, you're still producing a 1600x1200 JPEG at quality = 30.  Maybe one of them starts with a much bigger set of data (better camera sensor), but they're both down-scaling down to the same resolution (1600x1200) and performing the same JPEG compression.

Answer (score 1):

The same image on the two phones could have different sizes if the jpeg encoder uses different default quantization tables. Quantization is the only lossy step in jpeg encoding and it will have the biggest impact on final image files size - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Quantization

Btw, did you try visually inspecting the images on native resolution? A bigger screen might help identify the subtle differences in image quality, if any exist.

Comment: They're both 1600x1200.  Noticed some weirdness when I converted them to PNG then back to JPEG.  See comment above.

Answer (score 0):

It's all a matter of how the phone itself is built to handle the raw image taken from the camera.  It has to convert the image to JPG as best it can from what it actually saw.  When I process pictures taken with my DSLR in RAW, I can output JPGs of varying file sizes (same picture size), just by messing with the exposure, color curves, etc.  I'm doing that manually, but the phones have all of that logic built in to try and produce a picture that is generally pleasing to most people.  Point-and-shoot cameras do the same thing.

Based on this [site](http://www.gsmarena.com/piccmp.php3?idType=1&idPhone1=4212&idPhone2=4219&idPhone3=4238), it looks like the iPhone does a bit more compression and color guessing than the S3.  If you look closely, you can see that the colors are smoother with the picture taken by the S3, which takes more memory to store.  I have a feeling the Nexus uses a similar algorithm to the S3, it just doesn't have as good of a camera.

Comment: Doesn't it seem weird, though, that the 100k iPhone image looks significantly better than the 200k Nexus image (quality = 10)?  What if I turned the quality down to "1".  You'd *think* that would produce a very small image.  My guess that it'll still be bigger than 100k.

Could image metadata explain the difference?  That would be an awful lot of metadata...

Comment: No, it's not weird because the quality of the iPhone image is still at 30, right?  I'm a little surprised at the actual size difference of the images, but each phone is still using its own rendering/compression algorithm to create the picture.  Both sets of code are doing the same thing from your standpoint (size and quality), but the internals of how they do that are not controlled by you.

Comment: If resolution and pre-compression/pre-scaling data are held constant then image appearance and size should be a function of compression.  Maybe "30 on Android" isn't the same as "30 on iPhone", but shouldn't there exist some quality level on Android that produces a 100k image that's visually comparable to the 100k image produced by the iPhone?  This doesn't seem to be the case.  Even when I turn compression up to "10" the resulting image (which is noticeably inferior w.r.t. visual quality) is still twice as big as the iPhone image.

Comment: @user190758 can you upload some sample images?

Comment: Will need to retake new images since these contain sensitive data.  Some strangeness though. I took both images (the 100k iphone and 240k Android) and converted them to PNG, then converted them back to JPEG at a reasonably high quality (using Mac "Preview" app).  The sizes:  iPhone: 100k -> 1190k -> 226k, Android: 240k -> 870k -> 186k.  The raw data in the Android image actually compresses *better* when the JPEG compression is performed using the same app (Mac Preview).  But the image created Android is 240k whereas iPhone is 100k.

Comment: And now you're back to how the compression is actually being done.  The commonality in all of the lower file numbers is Apple.  Apple is doing things slightly differently than Google/Samsung.  I really don't think this is anything you can control.

Comment: I may have found a solution (tentatively- haven't tested yet).  It looks like the variability in file size is due to my relying on the camera API to do the compression.  If I use the methods in the Bitmap class, I think it does a better job.  This makes sense: the camera is likely sacrificing compression quality for speed.  So the solution may be to instruct the Camera to give me a raw image (or a super-high-quality JPEG), then compress it again manually using the Bitmap API.  Will post my results.

Comment: Yep.  The Camera API's JPEG compression is, generally speaking, really poor.  Worse on some devices than others.  The Bitmap API's JPEG compression is reliably good.